# How to make a python drop down box readonly?

Tags: python, django

How do you make a drop down box in python readonly to only display the previously chosen selection?

I already tried putting in a ReadOnlyFormMixin in the classes and that worked for most of the fields.

```
class ReadOnlyFormMixin(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ReadOnlyFormMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for key in self.fields.keys():
            self.fields[key].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # do not do anything
        pass
```

```
class ViewPartForm(ReadOnlyFormMixin, ModelForm):

    description = forms.CharField(label='Description',
                                  widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 3, 'cols': 35, 'max_length': 800}),
                                  required=True)

    char1 = forms.CharField(label='field2',
                             widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 1, 'cols': 25, 'max_length': 800}),
                             required=True)
    char2 = forms.CharField(label='field3',
                             widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 1, 'cols': 25, 'max_length': 800}),
                             required=True)

class Manufacturer1Form(ReadOnlyFormMixin, ModelForm):
    manufacturer = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Vendor.objects.filter(vendor_type='manufacturer').order_by('name'))

    class Meta:
        model = Manufacturer1Relationship
        exclude = ('part',)
```

Putting the ReadOnlyFormMixin worked for the first class but not for the second one. The choice field still lets users change what is selected.

Comment: What version of Django are you using?

Comment: I am using 2.1.2